# How to get previous location with react router?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I'm trying to get the previous location from react router. I've set up a reducer to listen for @@router/LOCATION_CHANGE and store the current and new locations but this action doesn't seem to get fired anymore?

Reducer looks like this:

```
const initialState = {
previousLocation: null,
currentLocation: null,
};
const routerLocations = function (state = initialState, action) {
  const newstate = { ...state };
  switch (action.type) {
      case "@@router/LOCATION_CHANGE":
          newState.previousLocation = state.currentLocation;
          newState.currentLocation = action.payload;
          return newState
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default routerLocations;
```

Is @@router/LOCATION_CHANGE the right thing to listen for?

I'm using

```
"react-router": "^4.2.0",
"react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
"react-router-redux": "^4.0.8",
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's better to import action type from `react-router-redux` directly like this:

```
import { LOCATION_CHANGE } from 'react-router-redux'
```

and then use it in your reducer. This action return new object after `history` is changed. Probably, you need only `pathname` property.

So, your reducer should be like this:

```
import { LOCATION_CHANGE } from 'react-router-redux'

const initialState = {
    previousLocation: null,
    currentLocation: null,
}

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case LOCATION_CHANGE:
            return {
                previousLocation: state.currentLocation,
                currentLocation: action.payload.pathname,
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

I faced with the problem that this action doens't fire on initial render. I've investigated and realized that it can be used only with `history` **earlier than version v4.0.0-2**.

This related to the internal implementation of the `react-router-redux`. Under the hood of the library, during initial render `getCurrentLocation` of `history` object is being called, which was removed in history version v4.0.0-2.

That's why you should downgrade your `history` version or try to subscribe on `history` changes and dispatch the action by yourself on initial render.

Comment: Thanks! Subscribing to history changes worked for me.

Comment: "This project is no longer maintained. For your Redux <-> Router syncing needs with React Router 4+"